# Defining external application dependency for PHP's composer.json and/or NodeJS's package.json

Tags: php, node.js, dependencies, composer-php, package.json

I'm not sure if this is a wild thought or what but is it possible to define an external dependency (such as an external utility/tool/program) for your PHP or NodeJS application via its dependency meta file (composer.json and package.json respectively)?

Say for example, before a user can use a certain PHP or NodeJS application, I want to make sure that the [festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/) program is installed prior to sourcing and installing the application and its other dependencies.

PS: I already googled this question prior to coming here but to no luck.

Thanks!!